# How to get all possible combination of two list in python

Tags: python

I have two list
countries = "AIA;BRA,AGO;DMA";
layer = "add;add,division;add,multiply"

I want to get the output like AIA-add, BRA-add, BRA-division, AGO-add, AGO-division, DMA-add, DMA-multiply.

I can achieve this using a 3 for loop but that affects the performance. Can I please get some help with optimization?

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you don't appear to have attempted anything on your own and you're just asking for code to solve your problem. Try researching how to get all possible combinations of 2 lists here on Stack Overflow, see what the output looks like, and if you still are having issues, post what they are specifically and share your code so viewers know what they're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) inside *list comprehension* with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) as:

```
from itertools import product

countries = "AIA;BRA,AGO;DMA"
layer = "add;add,division;add,multiply"

my_list = ['-'.join(s) for c, l in zip(countries.split(';'), layer.split(';')) for s in product(c.split(','), l.split(','))]
```

where `my_list` will hold:

```
['AIA-add', 'BRA-add', 'BRA-division', 'AGO-add', 'AGO-division', 'DMA-add', 'DMA-multiply']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` like this.

```
import itertools
list1=['a','b','c']
list2=[1,2]

[list(zip(x,list2)) for x in itertools.permutations(list1,len(list2))]
```